# How do I use two different images, one as a thumbnail and one as a linked image

Tags: wordpress, gallery, thumbnails, media

I want to do an image gallery in a page, where the linked image (a href) is different from the thumbnail's src. I need to have the ability to change the thumbnail image. Its important because for each image i have a different thumbnail (different content and size).

What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this plugin which have different options to set the image URL and image size

**Plugin :** [WP Gallery Custom Link](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-gallery-custom-links/)

May be it helps you to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you recommend some plugins for the same task in 2022? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin to asign different image sizes to different links.

**Plugin:** [gallery with custom links](http://wordpress.org/plugins/grid-gallery-with-custom-links/)

Comment: not good enough, i want to simplifies it, by that after the user  choose in the media upload the images he want to display in the gallery, he can upload for any image different thumbnail to display. I tried to add a file upload to the media upload, but it seems incapable for me